# WP7 PivotItem switch index

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

I need to switch Pivots in cs code, It works with manual indexes:

```
MyPivot.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

But something like this will be much better for me:

```
MyPivot.SelectedIndex = targetPivotItem.Index;
```

but I couldn't found any property for that...

Comment: Hi Janci, What do you mean by targetPivot.Index?

Comment: some property of targetPivot which leads to SelectedIndex, now I'm looking at DependencyProperty it probably can be done this way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is if you are not using `ItemsSource` on your `Pivot`.

```
Pivot1.SelectedIndex = Pivot1.Items.IndexOf(PivotItem1);
```

If you have set your `Pivot`'s ItemsSource to a collection, use following code:

```
Pivot1.SelectedItem = PivotItem1.DataContext;
```